# Unique values into Dataframe Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe and I need to create a dataframe with unique values, but when I use unique options this is getting created as object, how can keep/make it as dataframe so that I could use it for further use or merge or any other thing.
Dataframe Allow

```
Id code
1  0023
2  0145
3  0245
4  0056
5  0023
6  1182
7  0145

New=Allow['code'].unique()
```

This is not working as this getting created as object, but I need to get as dataframe. Let me know how can this be achieved

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem I tend to use `df.drop_duplicates('col')`.

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting this as a timeseries data, how can I make into dataframe.

Comment: Got it... Cur=New.to_frame()